# SQL Server linked server will not connect

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

I'm connected to our LAN via a client, and I am using SSMS v18.9.1 to  connect to two different SQL Server instances. I have read/write access to both. We will call them server A and server B.

I'd like be able to query server B from server A using a linked server.

Using the 'Linked Server' wizard I step through the setup, changed the security to 'Be made using the login's current security context' and after completing the steps I'm given the following errors.

> The linked server has been created but failed a connection test. Do you want to keep the linked server?
>
> Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

I then tried the following. Using the Windows app, "connect with remote desktop connection", I logged directly into the server I wanted to create the 'linked server' connection from, opened SSMS, tested the connection, and found it worked.

Why am I able to connect the linked server, when directly signed in to the server I'm making the connection from vs making the connection while signed in via a client?

I need to be able to connect via my client and have the linked server connect as it should.

Any help solving this is greatly appreciated

Comment: If servers are not on the domain or you are using local account, Windows authentication may not work for you.

Answer (score 1):

> Why am I able to connect the linked server, when directly signed in to the server I'm making the connection from vs making the connection while signed in via a client?

Because performing impersonation when the user has logged on locally is always allowed.  The user has a local logon so performing network access using that user's NTLM hash or Kerberos ticket is not considered a security risk.

However when the user has only performed a network authentication to the server, the server is not allowed to impersonate the user for other network resources without additional security configuration.  This scenario is called a "double-hop" and performing double-hop authentication is only possible if you've configured the server (in AD) to allow [Kerberos Delegation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/kerberos/kerberos-constrained-delegation-overview).  Consider the blast radius if an IIS or SQL Server got compromized if it could then impersonate any user across the network.

Essentially your Domain Admins must approve this server for any double-hop authentication it performs, and you've got to have the correct SPN's configured.  There's a [tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39046) to help you get the configuration right.

So options include:

1. Jump through the hoops of getting Kerberos Constrained Delegation working,
2. Use SQL Auth for your linked server
3. Access the Linked Server from a SQL Agent Job, which always starts with a local logon.